# Is there a way to assign a stacked object to the allocated memory using placement new?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, placement-new

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object {
public:
    Object() { cout << "Object constructor!" << endl; }
    ~Object() { cout << "Object destructor!" << endl; }
    Object(const Object& obj) { information = obj.information; cout << "Copy constructor!" << endl; }
    void setInformation(const string info) { information = info; }
    string getInformation() const { return information; }
private:
    string information;
};

class Storage {
public:
    Storage() { object = static_cast<Object*>(operator new(sizeof(Object))); }
    ~Storage() { operator delete(object); }

    void setObject(const Object& obj) {
        // Todo: assign obj to the allocated space of the pointer object
    }
private:
    Object* object;
};

int main()
{
    Object o;
    o.setInformation("Engine");
    Storage storage;
    storage.setObject(o);
    return 0;
}
```

In Storage I am allocating space to store one object of type Object without creating it. I am using placement new for that which allocates a memory, and freeing it in the destructor. I know that I can use

```
object = new(object) Object()
```

to construct an object. But can I put in the memory an object that is already created? In my case call method setObject(). If yes what problems I can encounter with such memory management? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problems here are numerous. Besides `Storage` violating the Rule Of Three itself, if `setObject` never gets called, the destructor attempts to `delete` something that wasn't constructed as an instance of the object. Kaboom.

Comment: You need to allocate your object somewhere, and there is no reason why the object from `setObject` was allocated on the stack and there is no way for you to retrieve it as it's const. So you can't assign it to your pointer. Use a unique_ptr to store the object and create a new one when you have a call to setObject. If you don't want to create a new obe, pass in a unique_ptr. Be explicit about your memory management.

Comment: Sam, I know that but thanks for pointing that out. The program is not finished yet. And that is why I decided to ask the specific question first: how to fill method setObject(). I know that I have to call destructor explicitly later.

Comment: Are you limited to c++11?

Comment: No, I am not limited. As I understand this can't be done in C++ 11 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve the behavior you are trying to implement would be to use `std::optional` from C++17. It will allow you to "reserve" the memory for your `Object` without constructing it and **without using the heap**. It will also handle all the constructor and destructor calls.

This also can be done without `std::optional`, but you will essentially have to implement a similar solution yourself. In any case you will need an additional member to specify whether object constructed or not, so you can properly handle the destruction and assignment.

Then your `setObject` method will look something like this:

```
void setObject(const Object& obj) {
    if (constructed) {
        *object = obj;
    } else {
        new (object) Object(obj);
        constructed = true;
    }
}
```

To make use of move semantics you can modify your method like this:

```
void setObject(Object obj) {
    if (constructed) {
        *object = std::move(obj);
    } else {
        new (object) Object(std::move(obj));
        constructed = true;
    }
}
```

Note that now `setObject` accepts it parameter by-value so it can be used with both lvalue and rvalue references to construct the parameter which is then will be moved into the member.

Comment: Thanks, yes that I was suppose to do afterwards.

Comment: @Oleg, it would still be better just to use `std::optional`, but if you want to do it yourself you can get rid of the dynamic allocation using a buffer `char buffer[sizeof(Object)]` or a more elegant solution would be to use a one member `union { Object obj; }`.

Comment: Am I correct that if I use the setObject that you have wrote I need to do next: if (constructed)
            (*object).~Object(); in the destructor?

Comment: @Oleg, yes and you can use `object->~Object();` for better readability.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing if copy constructor is deleted?

Comment: @Oleg, you can use move constructor if it's available. You'll need to change the signature of `setObject` to accept rvalue reference or accept by-value and then use `std::move` in the body.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to understand memory management more deeply. But for sure I will use C++ 17 (std::optional) for this kind of problem.

Comment: @r3musn0x `char buffer[sizeof(Object)]` is incorrect, since it does not guarantee proper alignment. Use, e.g., `std::aligned_storage` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Placement new is a pretty advanced construct, and the thought of having an `Object*` that actually points to uninitialized memory is rather terrifying. May I suggest you make your life easier?

```
class Storage {
    void setObject(const Object& obj) {
        if (object) {
            *object = obj;
        } else {
            object.reset(new Object(obj));
        }
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Object> object;
};
```

This requires a copy constructor and assignment operator on the `Object` class, but is much more idiomatic C++. And in the `Object` implementation as shown, the default, compiler-provided implementations are already fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify:

> But can I put in the memory an object that is already created?

No, you cannot. There is no way how to move objects in memory in C++. For *trivially copyable* types, you can copy (e.g, by `memcpy` or `memmove`) their memory representations. But this actually does not move anything. Moreover, your `Object` class is not trivially copyable.

What you can *move* is the contents of objects, which is what move semantics is for.